# Asking for a person: "Could I speak 'to'/'with' Kristina?"

Tags: phrase-usage, prepositions

If one is asking for a person, what should s/he say—1 or 2?

1. Could I speak **to** Kristina?
2. Could I speak **with** Kristina?

Answer (score 4):

Both *speak to*, and *speak with* are used.

> Can I speak to Susan?

> Can I speak with you for a minute?

In both the cases, the meaning is "have a conversation with somebody." The difference is that *speak to* (or *talk to*) is less polite, since it put the emphasis on one doing the conversation, while *speak with* (or *talk with*) is more polite, since it doesn't put the emphasis on just one doing the conversation.

Comment: Agreed. Though "with" would be considered more polite, as you are implying a two-way conversation of (hopefully) equal importance. "to" is less polite, as the emphasis is on yourself doing the talking. It might also infer that you have something negative to say.

Comment: In the UK at least, there isn't such a difference in terms of being polite. People normally just say *speak to* or *talk to*. I have not heard anyone other than Americans say *speak with* and it sounds really weird and unusual in the UK.

Comment: @Tristan In my opinion, it is the same in the US. I don't really think there is much difference in politeness between "talk to" and "talk with"

Comment: I agree with this answer, but would like to know if there is any difference between using "can" and "could" in this context? `Could I please speak to Kristina?` sounds as natural as `Can I please speak to Kristina?`, if not more polite.

Comment: @Garreh _Could_ is used to politely ask something; _may_ is used to politely ask permission. _Can_ is informally used to ask permission. The fact I switched from _could_ to _can_ is purely random. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

In the UK at least, the choice would be number one. People normally just say *speak to* or *talk to*. There seems to be a USA/UK difference here. I have not heard anyone other than Americans say speak with and it sounds really weird and unusual in the UK.

Comment: From a quick look at [GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/), it doesn't appear that this is actually the case...  There are a lot of results in the UK, and a fairly large proportion appear to be followed by a complement such as *him* or *someone*.

Comment: In all my life, I haven't heard anyone British use it. The only reason that I know it is because I have heard Americans say it on television programmes and it is very different from what British people normally say.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine and:

> mainly UK "Can I speak to Dan please?"
>
> mainly US "Can I speak with Scott please?"

source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speak)